# How could I use Python, Selenium and PhantomJS to download/upload MEGA file?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Everything is in the title.
I run Python 2.7 on Windows 7, I have PhantomJS installed and Selenium ready to use, but I would like some help to get started!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Harry - This question automate download / upload is not well regarded.
So I can not give you the code ready, even for knowledge, it is good to learn and develop yourself! So I will give you the ropes, using only **PhantomJS + CasperJS**...

From what I saw of the site (mega.co.nz) steps for scraping, would be as follows:

- You will need to access the login page: https://mega.co.nz/#login
- Fill the fields login and password and click the login button
- Once logged in, you will have to access the upload page and upload the desired files to the site. To perform the file type fields fill, you should use the `casper.fill` property CasperJS.

The principle is that! The CasperJS is a magical world, and you can do much with it ...